# Create UICollectionViewCell in Interface Builder

Tags: ios, iphone, uicollectionviewcell

I would like to create all the cells from UICollectionView in interface builder and not in code.

I mean I want to do this without cellForItemAtIndexPath method. Just add few UICollectionViewCells in interface builder each one with label that I'll create in interface builder. Is it possible?

Comment: This sounds like a static table view. Could you use a table view instead?

Comment: I need something like a static table but I need it to rearrange according to interface orientation (portrait landscape) that's why I thought UICollectionView would be a good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possibile :) you can just create one or more UICollectioViewCell with Identifier, and use them in the code by datasource methods (cellForRow.., section number.., rowForSection.., etc.)